# Copy Files from Paths A to Paths B Using VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, copy

I need to move all specified files to the specified folders.

I have the complete path for each file stored as an array in VBA. (the path format is something like this: "c:\folder\file.pdf" - basically the complete stuff)

I have a second array which stores the destination folder.

Both arrays are the same size and its order corresponds to one another.

No need for checking if the files exists, i'm very sure the listed files in the array will be available.

My need is to input array 1 and array 2 and bang, magic done.

If possible the avoidance of loops, i would appreciate

My code so far:

```vb
Sub Copy()
   Dim array01 As Range
   
   ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pt_filepath").PivotFields("Custom.99").PivotFilters. _
        Add2 Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:="01/09/2021", Value2:="30/09/2021"
        
   ActiveSheet.PivotTables("pt_filepath").PivotSelect "'complete path'[All]", _
        xlLabelOnly, True
   
   'filters a pivot table and selects its contents, the data which have the complete pathway to each file.
   
   Set array01 = Selection
   
   For Each Cell In array01
      FileCopy Cell, "C:\temp\"
   Next Cell
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please note that SO is not a code writing service, you are to make your own research and attempt then ask a question if you encounter any problem with your code that you can't resolve.

Comment: Having said that, there are plenty of examples that you can get from google to achieve what you want.

Comment: i know that, i'm searching a lot for this but can't manage to have. i've tried a lot of code exaples found right here. i did not find anything that i could just input two lists (from and to) and get the job done.

Comment: @Guiherme If you have tried something, then edit your question and post your best code attempt so that we can help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using os.system().

```
For file in dir2:
   os.system('cd dir1')
   os.system('MOVE '+ file + dest_directory)
```

This probably wont work just pasting in but something to get you started